# Buffered Writer unable to process from array

Tags: java, arrays, ascii, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am using a bufferedwriter to write to a file from an array:

```
int[] scores = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  scores[i] = 2; //Array of twos
}  

try {
  BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Scores.txt")));
    output.flush();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      output.write(scores[i]);
      output.newLine();
    }
    output.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
  //Do something
}
```

This code ends up entering junk values, i.e., ASCII characters for borders, even though the integer array has valid numbers. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Please replace one of the tags with the language you're using, so that the best people will notice it.

Comment: @xZhou21 what do you mean by arrays having valid numbers? Example would be nice.

Comment: Array of what? If it's an array of `int,` you will be calling `write(`int),` which writes the bottom 16 bits as a `char.` No binary-to-decimal conversion.

Comment: Your question is unclear, elaborate on junk values, show examples

Comment: @Suspended for clarification, instead of changing the text file to twos, it changes to ASCII characters like ASCII 192 (the left edge of a rectangle) http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with `output.write(Integer.toString(scores[i]));`, so you write strings, instead of ints?